# Exclude routerLinkActive styleclass for some routes

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

I have a page header with 4 main tabs. MY PROFILE tab (`/profile`) has Action Items child tab available at route `/profile/action-items`.
I also have ACTION ITEMS main tab, which basically redirects user to `/profile/action-items`. That is the root cause of my problem. When `/profile/action-items` route is active, both MY PROFILE and ACTION ITEMS tab names are highlighted because of `routerLinkActive` usage. However, I want only ACTION ITEMS to be highlighted at `/profile/action-items`

[image: app header]

I tried to use `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}"`, but in that case MY PROFILE is not highlighted when we navigate to its subtabs, e.g. `/profile/bookmarks`

Is there a way to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`routerLinkActive` has no inherent support for the desired behaviour as far as I know. The solution here would be to instead use `ngClass` and subscribe to the `ActivatedRoute`, applying the desired `active` class depending on the precise route.

Comment: It seems like you are right. It worked for me. However, I have found the desired feature in Angular's backlog https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13205 (not implemented yet)

Comment: I guess you could always replace `{exact: true}` with `{exact: testResult}` and have `testResult` react to the `ActivatedRoute` if you really want to keep to a `routerLinkActive` scheme.